# Laravel: The GET method is not supported for this route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Ando un poco desesperado con esto. Estoy desarrollando una API en Laravel y, en local funciona perfectamente, pero no en mi servicio de hosting. Mi intención es que, dicho servicio sea accesible desde una app móvil. Tengo el siguiente código:

archivo **api.php**

```php
Route::post('/test', 'testController@test') ;
```

archivo **testController.php**

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class testController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function test(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->json(['mensaje' => 'Accediendo mediante post']); 
    }
}
```

Cuando realizo la petición utilizando POSTMAN, siempre emite el mismo error: **The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST**. Curiosamente, en POSTMAN utilizo explícitamente el método POST.

[image: petición con POSTMAN]

Investigando por la red he leído que puede ser debido a la política de CORS y he instalado [spatie/laravel-cors](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-cors) dejando la configuración por defecto, pero nada, me sigue mostrando el mismo error. ¿Alguna ayuda, por favor?

Comment: Lo mas posible es que si sea por el CORS. Que servidor de aplicaciones utilizas?

Comment: Utilizo el hosting de aruba.it

Comment: Revertí tu edición, pues no es correcto que publiques la solución en el cuerpo de la pregunta, para eso en la parte inferior existe una zona llamada *Tu respuesta* espacio en el cual puedes publicar como lo resolviste. Saludos